# Specify multiple JSON types for a nested JSON items? Error: Schema expected Integer but got a number

Tags: json, power-automate

I received the following error in a Power Automate script:

Error: Invalid type. Expected Integer but got a Number.
ValidationFailed: The schema validation failed.

Schema is:

`"complexity":{ type:"Integer" }`

Input is:

`"complexity":0.4`

Answer (score 1):

You can specify both JSON types for the specific item:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": ["integer", "number"]
}
```

This will allow the input to be either an integer or a number.